# перестали работать кнопки Unity

Tags: unity3d

Прикрепил камеру к персонажу, но необходимо, чтобы кнопка "в меню" была постоянно в углу. Я кинул её на камеру и она теперь там и остаётся, но не считываются нажатия. Какие есть варианты закрепления объектов или распознавания нажатий для платформы андроид.

Comment: А Что за кнопка? UI или GUI?

Comment: кнопка UI, коллайдер и всё что надо есть на ней

Comment: А у вас на сцене висит EventSystem ?

Comment: Да, и кнопки, которые не на камере, а на канвасе работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используй расположение в углу и размести так, чтобы было видно полностью. Сдвинь к центру на половину размера картинки, в моем случае размер 100, а я сдвигаю на 50.

И есть вопрос, зачем тебе коллайдер на UI, если оно и так видит границы изображения?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Насчёт коллайдера, в 2Д у меня почему-то не работают кнопки без него.

Comment: В таком случае они видимо нужны, хотя у меня все работает и без них.